# DBUNIT MySQL Using Square Brackets

Tags: mysql, dbunit

I am using dbunit for testing, dbunit fails with incorrect query syntax error. Looking at the query, there are square brackets guarding the column names, and I understand square brackets are not acceptable in MYSQL. How do I get rid of the square brackets?

```
testException = com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 

You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 

'[sades] set [CORRELATION_ID] = 'ZYX', [LMT_COUNT] = 132.58000000, [SPO' at line 1]], class dirties context [false], class mode [null], method dirties context [false].
```

Comment: Does DBUnit have the notion of "SQL dialects"? Apparently it's thinking that it's connecting to a Microsoft database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thank you for the clue. Yes, I had incorrect properties set that are favorable to MSSQL, and not MYSQL. Thanks ton.